# SQL View with count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, c, sql-server, count, subquery

I have a nodejs app with SQL Server. I want to be able to have a View where I can get a tally of number of users, projects, tasks for multiple organization. Let's say I have 4 tables as follows:
**TABLES:**

- **Organization**: orgId(PK), orgName
- **Project**: projId(PK), orgId(FK), projName
- **Tasks**: taskId(PK), projId(FK), taskName
- **Users**: userId(PK), orgId(FK), userName

**VIEW:**

- **OrganizationStats**: numberOfProjects, numberOfUsers, numberOfTasks orgId(FK)

It was suggested to use something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_OrganisationStats AS

    SELECT {Columns from OrganizationStats},
           P.Projects AS NumProjects
    FROM dbo.OrganizationStats OS
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Projects
                      FROM dbo.Projects P
                      WHERE P.OrgID = OS.OrgID) P;
```

My problem is I am having problem adding the count for Tasks and Users in addition to the Project within the same View. Any help would be appreciate it.

```
**Sample Data:** 
* **Organization**: orgId(PK), orgName
1, ACME Inc.
2, Walmart Inc.
3, YoYo Inc.

* **Project**: projId(PK), orgId(FK), projName
1, 1, ACME Project 1
2, 1, ACME Project 2
3, 2, Walmart Project 1
4, 2, Walmart Project 2
5, 2, Walmart Project 3

* **Tasks**: taskId(PK), projId(FK), taskName
1, 1, Task 1 for Acme Project 1
2, 1, Task 2 for Acme Project 1
3, 4, Task 1 for Walmart Project 2

* **Users**: userId(PK), orgId(FK), userName
1, 1, Bob
2, 1, Alex
3, 1, Jim
4, 2, John
```

Expected Result
**VIEW:**

```
* **OrganizationStats**: numberOfProjects, numberOfUsers, numberOfTasks orgId(FK)

2, 3, 2, 1
3, 1, 1, 2
0, 0 ,0, 3
```

Comment: Can you put sample data and expected results please:

Comment: Sure.. updated the original question

Comment: an explanation has been added to my answer

Comment: Select and Script both has been updated according to your comment(test), check it again please

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
select o.orgid, 
    count(distinct p.projid) as cnt_projects, 
    count(distinct u.userid) as cnt_users,
    count(*) cnt_tasks
from organization o
inner join projects p on p.orgid = o.orgid
inner join users    u on u.orgid = o.orgid
inner join tasks    t on t.projid = p.projid and t.userid = u.userid
group by o.orgid
```

Comment: Sorry, the edit I have done was by mistake. I was doing the edit to my post, it seems the sequence of answers has changed suddenly and I clicked edit on your post. Sorry again, I do not have the ability to rellback.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT O.orgId
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT U.userId) AS 'numberOfUsers'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT P.projId) AS 'numberOfProjects'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT T.taskId) AS 'numberOfTasks'
FROM Organization O
LEFT JOIN Users U ON O.orgId = U.orgId
LEFT JOIN Project P ON O.orgId = P.orgId
LEFT JOIN Tasks T ON P.projId = T.projId
GROUP BY O.orgId
```

SCRIPT USED:

```
CREATE TABLE Organization (orgId INT , orgName VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE Project(projId INT, orgId INT, projName VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE Tasks (taskId INT, projId INT, taskName VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE Users (userId INT, orgId INT, userName  VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO Organization VALUES (1, 'ORG 1'), (2, 'ORG 2')
INSERT INTO Organization VALUES (3, 'ORG 3')
INSERT INTO Project VALUES (1,1, 'PRO 11'), (2,2, 'PRO 21'), (3,2, 'PRO 22')
INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES (1, 1, 'TASK 11'), (2, 1, 'TASK 21'), (3, 2, 'TASK 32'), (4, 2, 'TASK 42'), (5, 2, 'TASK 52')
INSERT INTO Users VALUES (1, 1, 'USER 11'), (2, 1, 'USER 12'), (3, 2, 'USER 21')
```

RESULTS :

```
+-------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| orgId | numberOfUsers | numberOfProjects | numberOfTasks |
+-------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| 1     | 2             | 1                | 2             |
+-------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| 2     | 1             | 2                | 3             |
+-------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
| 3     | 0             | 0                | 0             |
+-------+---------------+------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: try adding the org with no projects. your solution doesn't work for that scenario

Comment: @Sean D, the select has been updated, check it again